# How to exclude NAs? (fitdist function)

Tags: r, statistics, na, fitdistrplus

I have 100x2 data frame DFN. Running `fitdist` on column DFN$Lret gives error message "function mle failed to estimate the parameters, with the error code 100". I figured the reason is the last row contains an NA. Hence I run `fitdist` excluding NAs, and now I get error "data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1". Any thoughts on how to resolve this? Thanks very much.

```
DFN <- structure(list(LRet = c(0.0011, 0, -0.0026, 0, -0.0015, 0.0038, 3e-04, -0.0021, 4e-04, -0.001, 0, 0.0019, -6e-04, -8e-04, -5e-04, -8e-04, 3e-04, -5e-04, -0.0026, 0.0014, 7e-04, 0, -2e-04, 0.0011, -0.0025, 0.0042, 0.0022, -0.0017, -0.0058, 1e-04, 2e-04, 8e-04, -9e-04, -0.0014, -0.0014, -0.001, -0.0032, -0.0015, 6e-04, -8e-04, 0.001, -0.0014, -0.0017, -8e-04, -0.001, 0.0011, 0.0013, -0.001, 5e-04, 9e-04, -8e-04, -0.0025, 0.0027, 6e-04, 2e-04, -6e-04, 9e-04, -3e-04, -7e-04, 3e-04, 0, 2e-04, -6e-04, 1e-04, -1e-04, -7e-04, -8e-04, 7e-04, -1e-04, -7e-04, 7e-04, 8e-04, -8e-04, 8e-04, 0.0058, -1e-04, -5e-04, 0.0027, -0.0012, 7e-04, 7e-04, 0, 3e-04, -1e-04, 2e-04, -2e-04, -0.0013, -1e-04, 1e-04, -0.0011, 0.0013, 2e-04, -3e-04, -7e-04, 0, 0.0015, 1e-04, 3e-04, -0.0012, NA), LRetPct = c("0.11%", "0.00%", "-0.26%", "0.00%", "-0.15%", "0.38%", "0.03%", "-0.21%", "0.04%", "-0.10%", "0.00%", "0.19%", "-0.06%", "-0.08%", "-0.05%", "-0.08%", "0.03%", "-0.05%", "-0.26%", "0.14%", "0.07%", "0.00%", "-0.02%", "0.11%", "-0.25%", "0.42%", "0.22%", "-0.17%", "-0.58%", "0.01%", "0.02%", "0.08%", "-0.09%", "-0.14%", "-0.14%", "-0.10%", "-0.32%", "-0.15%", "0.06%", "-0.08%", "0.10%", "-0.14%", "-0.17%", "-0.08%", "-0.10%", "0.11%", "0.13%", "-0.10%", "0.05%", "0.09%", "-0.08%", "-0.25%", "0.27%", "0.06%", "0.02%", "-0.06%", "0.09%", "-0.03%", "-0.07%", "0.03%", "0.00%", "0.02%", "-0.06%", "0.01%", "-0.01%", "-0.07%", "-0.08%", "0.07%", "-0.01%", "-0.07%", "0.07%", "0.08%", "-0.08%", "0.08%", "0.58%", "-0.01%", "-0.05%", "0.27%", "-0.12%", "0.07%", "0.07%", "0.00%", "0.03%", "-0.01%", "0.02%", "-0.02%", "-0.13%", "-0.01%", "0.01%", "-0.11%", "0.13%", "0.02%", "-0.03%", "-0.07%", "0.00%", "0.15%", "0.01%", "0.03%", "-0.12%", " NA%")), .Names = c("LRet", "LRetPct"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 901:1000)

library(fitdistrplus)

#Following gives error code 100
f1 <- fitdist(DFN$LRet,"norm") 

#Following gives error code 100
f1 <- fitdist(DFN$LRet,"norm", na.rm=T)

#Following gives error data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1"
f1 <- fitdist(na.exclude(DFN$LRet),"norm")
#Same result using na.omit
```

Please note if eliminating the last row, containing the NA, then the above code works fine. I would rather not have to eliminate the last row before running `fitdist` if can be avoided.

EDIT/UPDATE: eliminating the last row with the NA did solve the issue at first, but I am now failing to reproduce that consistently (i.e. have successfully run the code a few times after eliminating the last row, but not always). I am trying to understand why. I have tried using a 25x2 data frame, a 100x2, and a 300x2, as well as a vector, with similar results. Had thought the size of the data frame or vector may be part of the problem, hence the trials with different sizes.

Comment: You may try 100*DFN$LRet[!is.na(DFN$LRet)]. Your numbers are very close to zero so may need to be rescaled to avoid numeric problems in the mle calculation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Also found the poorly written `is.vector` section of the code, but it didn't solve the errors.) The `fitdist` function seems to have difficulty with vectors of small variance:

```
var( na.exclude(DFN$LRet))
[1] 2.220427e-06
```

You can get around that by multiplying by 10:

```
> f1 <- fitdist(10*c(na.exclude(DFN$LRet)),"norm")
> f1
Fitting of the distribution ' norm ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
          estimate  Std. Error
mean -0.0009090909 0.001490034
sd    0.0148256472 0.001032122
```

Standard probability theory lets you then correct those estimates: divide by 10 for the mean and by 100 for the variance (or 10 for the sd). The estimates from corrected `fitdist`-results are reasonably close to the sample values:

```
> all.equal( 0.0148256472/10 , sd(na.exclude(DFN$LRet) ) )
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.005089095"
```

Answer (score 6):

Debugging through `fitdist` shows

```
 if (!(is.vector(data) & is.numeric(data) & length(data) > 1)) 
    stop("data must be a numeric vector of length greater than 1")
```

Looking at `?is.vector`:

> ‘is.vector’ returns ‘TRUE’ if ‘x’ is a vector of the specified
>        mode having no attributes *other than names*.

`na.exclude` and its relatives (`na.omit` etc.) save information about excluded values as an attribute, so `is.vector()` becomes `FALSE` ...

One of the side effects of `c()` is to drop attributes other than names, so `is.vector(c(na.exclude(DFN$LRet)))` is `TRUE`, so

```
fitdist(c(na.exclude(DFN$LRet)), "norm")
```

at least doesn't get the "must be a numeric vector" error -- but I still get the "error 100".  Investigating further ...

Digging into the guts of `fitdist` some more, it appears that (as suggested by @42-) `optim()` is having trouble.  Specifically, it actually gets to an answer, but when it tries to calculate the Hessian of the solution it tries a negative value for the standard deviation parameter and barfs.

As an illustration, this works:

```
nn <- c(na.exclude(DFN$LRet))
fn <- function(x) -sum(dnorm(nn,mean=x[1],sd=x[2],log=TRUE))
optim(fn,par=c(mean(nn),sd(nn)),method="Nelder-Mead")
```

but this fails:

```
optim(fn,par=c(mean(nn),sd(nn)),method="Nelder-Mead",hessian=TRUE)
```